# Returning Null When Logcat Shows Not Null

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

trying to link fb with google auth
on logcat it say not null but

java.lang.NullPointerException at "Auth.currentUser "

```
fun linkFb() {
    Auth.addAuthStateListener {
        if (Auth == null) {
            Log.d("auth", "null")
        } else {
            Log.d("auth", "not null")

        }
    }

    val accessToken: AccessToken? = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
    val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken?.token.toString())
    Auth.currentUser!!.linkWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("Linking", "linkWithCredential:success")
                val user = Auth.currentUser
                updateUI(user)
            } else {
                Log.w("Linking", "linkWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                // updateUI(null)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: That is because it logs whether `Auth` is null; your code fails because `currentUser` is null. It is likely that the user is not loggen in yet, so there is no user to return. It's also good practice to only user `!!` when you are 100% sure it won't ever return null. What's a better approach instead is to also use `?` here.

Comment: yeah currentUser is null any idea why is it returning null i does not return null when signing in with google or signing with facebook without linking

Comment: Then the question is, what ar you trying to link the facebook account with? It should be another already signed in account. What you can do, is silently let users login anonymously: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth and link it with that